# Take 4 number's sums, then add those 4 numbers onto the sums of those 4 numbers, then repeat

Tags: python, math

Every year during the Super Bowl my dad does a bet with his friends, guess the last number of the score, and whoever guesses correctly wins 20 dollars. My question is hard to explain in words so I drew a diagram: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ECrH.jpg]

Basically I want to add 4 numbers (2, 3, 6, 7) onto each other, then take the 16 sums and add those 4 numbers onto each of the sums. 
After I repeat this process about 100 times I should have enough scores to find mostly all of the end numbers and the most likely end number.

This would take a lot of time to do by hand so I tried to write some code, but it was super hard for a starter like me (half done code on bottom).

I am wondering if there is some better way I can do this in Python 2.7.

```
sum_2 = {}
sum_3 = {}
sum_6 = {}
sum_7 = {}
nums = [2,3,6,7]
n_2 = 1
n_3 = 1
n_6 = 1
n_7 = 1
n_2_2 = n_2
n_3_3 = n_3
n_6_6 = n_6
n_7_7 = n_7
while n_7 < 10:
    for x in nums:
        sum_2[n_2] = x + x
        sum_2[n_2_2] = sum_2[n_2] + x
        n_2  = n_2 + 1
        n_2_2  = n_2 + 1

    for x in nums:
        sum_3[n_3] =  x + x
        sum_3[n_3_3] = sum_3[n_3] + x
        n_3 = n_3 + 1
        n_3_3  = n_3 + 1

    for x in nums:
        sum_6[n_6] =  x + x
        sum_6[n_6_6] = sum_6[n_6] + x
        n_6  = n_6 + 1
        n_6_6  = n_6 + 1

    for x in nums:
        sum_7[n_7] =  x + x
        sum_7[n_7_7] = sum_7[n_7] + x
        n_7  = n_7 + 1
        n_7_7  = n_7 + 1
else:
    print sum_2
    print sum_3
    print sum_6
    print sum_7
```

Comment: You can use itertools to get permutations of the original numbers and then add the sums of the permutations to you list and loop around a bunch of times.
Since this is a football application, do you have an idea of how many total scoring events you want (i.e. a range of how many numbers you should be adding together?) 100 scores seems like a lot.  Also, i expect you'd want to assign probabilities to each of your starting four numbers since safeties are improbable relative to field goals, etc., and you could do that by not only outputting the sum of n events but the combined probability

Comment: @Matt Could you give me some example code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nums = [2,3,6,7]
x = []
for i in range(5):
    for p in itertools.product(nums, repeat=i):
        x.append(sum(p))
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. **EDIT,** when I made a new file and ran it, nothing happened.

Comment: @distaf Try to add a `print(x)` below the `for`-loop